# Trouble retrieving correctly encoded string output using Python subproccess function to call .NET app

Tags: python, c#, .net, subprocess

I am using following code for retrieving output of dotnet app with python script, doing so I am getting returned string in different encoding than whenever I am getting it directly from the dotnet app...

This is the retriever script in python:

```
import subprocess

def call_dotnet_app(input_string):
    try:
        #comm with app
        dotnet_process = subprocess.Popen(['dotnet', r'Correct_Pathing'],
                                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        #input the string from P to dotnet
        dotnet_process.stdin.write(input_string)
        dotnet_process.stdin.flush()

        #wait for dotnet to finish and retrieve output
        output, _ = dotnet_process.communicate()
        return output.strip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The .NET runtime or your_app.dll could not be found.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error executing the .NET app: {e}")

 #Call the .NET app and capture the output
input_string = "1234"
output = call_dotnet_app(input_string)

#Printing the output 
print("Output:", output)
```

This is the .NET app sample output:

```
172.31.0.98  -  Sociální zařízení Nov
172.28.143.243  - pokusné pracoviště
```

This is the outpus i get whenever i retrieve it using Python:

```
172.31.0.98  -   Soci lnˇ zaýˇzenˇ Nov
172.28.143.243  -   pokusn‚ pracoviçtŘ
```

Note the symbols that are showing in 'wrong encoding' are used in EU (ANSI 1250) if that helps solving the issue somehow

I have tried defining the encoding inside Popen with "encoding='utf-8' but that raises an UnicodeDecodeError stating the .NET app is not in utf-8